# migratedFromWorkflowRuleName contains an invalid workflow rule name

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow

Just ~2 days ago, we started encountering the error in the title in different scenarios. Moreover, when performing the scenario again after few minutes, the error doesn't occur anymore. In the picture below, the error occurred when opportunity stage is changed. Upon googling, migratedFromWorkflowRuleName is a [flow metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm).

[image: Snag in Opportunity]

Since we have already migrated all our workflow rules to flow, we have no idea. What does the error *mean*? Most likely this affects flows that are from the migrate to flow tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this also happened in our sandbox yesterday, I spent the whole day trying to figure out what was happening, but I opened a case with Salesforce and there is supposed to be a patch for this, I don't know if the case is public but the url is this:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/case-view?caseId=500Hx00000JI9ZlIAL
case number: 45236286

It might already be working for the requester at this point

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello. Thanks! I think everyone except those in your org cannot view the link. Did SF provide a root cause for this issue?

Comment: No, they only said that "a patch was delayed due to some problem but we are planning on updating instance <theInstanceOfMyOrg> today" and that was it... since there was no longer a problem in our Org I just didn't ask anymore and the case was closed